# How to Mount Hugepages inside Docker

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, docker, virtualization

I have an application running inside Docker requires Huge-page to run .Now I tried following set of command for same.

```
CMD ["mkdir", "-p" ,"/dev/hugepages"]
CMD ["mount" ,"-t", "hugetlbfs" , "none", "/dev/hugepages"]
CMD ["echo 512" ,">" ,"/proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages"]
CMD ["mount"]
```

But I don't see Hugepages gets mounted from mout command, why?

Could anyone please point me out, is it possible to do it?

Comment: you might need to run your container in [privileged mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a number of things at hand;

First of all, a Dockerfile only has a *single* command (`CMD`); what you're doing won't work; if you need to do multiple steps when the container is started, consider using an entrypoint script, for example [this is the entrypoint script of the official mysql image](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh)

Second, doing `mount` in a container requires additional privileges. You can use `--privileged` but that is probably far too wide of a step, and gives far too much privileges to the container. You can try running the container with `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN`in stead.

#### Alternative solution

A much cleaner solution could be to mount hugepages on the *host*, and give the container access to that device, e.g.;

```
docker run --device=/dev/hugepages:/dev/hugepages ....
```

Comment: Not sure if this works any longer... now you get adding custom device "/dev/hugepages": not a device node.